# EGF by recursion

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find an EGF for the simplest series:
$$ {a_n = \alpha n + \beta } $$

With $A(x) = \sum\limits_{n\geq0} \frac{a_nx^x}{n!} $ I have, using one approach:

$$A(x) = \sum\limits_{n\geq0}\frac{\alpha n x^n}{n!} + 
\sum\limits_{n\geq0}\frac{\beta x^n}{n!} 
=\alpha x e^x + \beta e^x$$

The above answer is correct. However when I try to do the same thing using recursion (which used to work for me in ordinary generating series I get the wrong answer).
$$ a_{n+1} = a_n+\alpha \space\space (a_0=\beta)$$
Multiplying and summing the left hand side for $n \geq 0$:
$$ \frac{a_1x^0}{0!}+\frac{a_2x^1}{1!}+...=(\frac{A(x)-\beta}{x})$$
For the right hand side:
$$A(x) + \alpha e^x$$
So if we equate the two we get:
$$A(x)-\beta = xA(x) + x\alpha e^x => A(x)=\frac{\beta+\alpha x e^x}{1-x} $$
Could someone point the mistake I'm making?

Comment: Yes. In the condition you wrote $a^nx^x$. It should be $a_nx^n$?

Comment: That's right, I've edited it. It still makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you are using the calculus for ordinary generating functions even though we are now dealing with an exponential generating function.

We have
$$
a_{n+1} = a_n + \alpha,
$$
and we let
$$
A(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}.
$$
Then the equation for the generating function becomes
$$
A'(x) = A(x) + \alpha e^x, \quad A(0) = \beta
$$
(that's where your mistake is). Solving this ordinary differential equation gives you the result you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Silly of me not to spot it ;)